# how do i add together the data from 2 imported ranges?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to importrange from multiple workbooks into a new workbook and add the data together.

So, I have workbookA, workbookB and workbookC. I am importing data from 1 cell on workbook A and B into a cell on workbook C and would like to add the data together.

I have tried,

`=SUM(IMPORTRANGE("locationA","spec template!d21") + IMPORTRANGE("locationB","spec template!d21"))`

Comment: What error are you gettting?

Comment: It is just giving me the number from location A, and nothing from location B

Comment: On test spreadsheets, your formula works for me.  However, if I put a non-number in the cell of location B, then I get only the value from location A.

Comment: Problem solved, issue with the number format in one of the locations. All sorted now thanks. I didnt even think to check that they were formatted the same way.

Comment: No problem.  Glad I could help.

Comment: fyi, you used "+" in the sum formula. Not the best idea to have reliable results in general.